# Ordinary Differential Equation question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm stuck with the following ODE :

$$y(4x+3y^3)\,dx+x(2x+5y^3)\,dy=0$$

It's not exact and the integrating factor is neither a function of $x$ nor a function of $y$ alone. Need some advice on how to get started... Thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear, is there an answer? i.e. is the answer in the back of your textbook? Just curious...

Comment: @Sapphire There's no such thing as 'the' integrating factor. There could several integrating factors and they don't necessarily come as a result of standard techniques.

Comment: @imranfat Yes, (x^3)*(y^2)*(x + y^3) = c.

Comment: it's a homogeneous equation (invariant under $x\to \lambda^3x$, $y\to\lambda y$). That should get you started.

Comment: Thanks Sapphire (even though way too late). It's a good exercise also for me to work on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** To simplify things (and since everything is just nice powers of $x$ and $y$), let's assume that the integrating factor is of the form $\mu(x,y) = x^my^n$ for some $m,n\in \Bbb Z$. Then multiplying through by $\mu$ yields:
$$
\underbrace{(4x^{m+1}y^{n+1} + 3x^my^{n+4})}_M \, dx + \underbrace{(2x^{m+2}y^n + 5x^{m+1}y^{n+3})}_N \, dy = 0
$$

Hence, since we want $M_y = N_x$, we obtain:
$$
4(n+1)x^{m+1}y^n + 3(n+4)x^my^{n+3} = 2(m+2)x^{m+1}y^n + 5(m+1)x^my^{n+3}
$$

By comparing coefficients, we obtain a system of two equations with two unknowns. Solving this system yields $m=2$ and $n=1$, so we may multiply through by $\mu(x,y)=x^2y$.

Comment: Aha, why didn't I think of that...Thanks a lot :)